# phonegap with $.ajax (Android)

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

Using phonegap, I am trying to get json data from the server. But it is always executing onCreateReportError method and giving status=0. I went through other stackoverflow's related question, nothing seems to be wrong in my code. What could be the issue?

```
$('#randomPerson').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url : 'http://localhost:9090/mvc-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/person/random',
            crossDomain: true,
            beforeSend : function() {$.mobile.loading('show')},
            complete   : function() {$.mobile.loading('hide')},
            dataType   : 'json',
          data : {},
          success: onCreateReportSuccess,
         error : onCreateReportError
        });


    function onCreateReportSuccess(person, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('Status: ' + textStatus);
        $('#personResponse').text(person.name + ', age ' + person.age);
    }

    function onCreateReportError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Status: ' + textStatus);
        console.log('Error: ' + errorThrown);
        alert('Error creating report');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you testing on a device? Is `http://localhost:9090/` reachable from there?

Comment: Can you please mark as answered if this was the correct answer?